# B-1 visa holder applying for J-1 visa

Tags: usa, j-visa

I currently hold a B-1 visa that's valid for the next 2 years. I plan to apply for a J1 research scholars program.

I can't decide which is the best way to go about applying for the J1. If I start the process in my country, would I still be able to travel to USA on my B1 while waiting for the J-1 to be approved? If I were able, and the J-1 were approved, would I have to go back to my home country and then re-enter the US on the J-1?

Or, is it better to apply for J-1 while I'm in the States? I read that this option might take much longer (6 months).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to travel on B-1 until your J-1 is approved.

The rest is a matter of personal preferences. Describe "better" and the answer will change. Both routes are possible.